# Error trying to get property of non-object di code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

good evening, I get this problem in the code igniter when it will display data.
in the view section I write

```
<?= base_url() . 'lihat/transaksi/' . $transaksi->id_pemesanan ?>" target="_blank">#<?= $transaksi->id_pemesanan ?>
```

the controller is written like this

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max-size'] = 10240;

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->load->model('KonfirmasiModel');
        $this->load->model('TransaksiModel');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['transaksi'] = $this->TransaksiModel->myTransaction();
        $this->template('index',$data);
    }

    public function template($page, $data = null)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/pelanggan/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/pelanggan/sidemenu');
        $this->load->view('pelanggan/konfirmasi/'.$page,$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/pelanggan/footer');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('foto')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->template('index',$error);
            return;
        }

        $data = array(
            'pelanggan_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'pemesanan_id' => $this->input->post('pemesanan_id'),
            'nama_bank' => $this->input->post('nama_bank'),
            'no_rek' => $this->input->post('no_rek'),
            'pemilik' => $this->input->post('pemilik')
        );

        // UPLOAD IMAGE
        $this->upload->do_upload('foto');
        $data['foto'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');

        // var_dump($data);

        // INSERT INTO DATABASE
        $this->db->insert('konfirmasi',$data);

        // REDIRECT TO USER PAGE
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Konfirmasi berhasil dilakukan!');
        redirect(base_url() . 'pelanggan/');
    }

}
```

the model is written like this

```
class KonfirmasiModel extends CI_Model {

    public function getConfirmation()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('konfirmasi');
        $this->db->join('pelanggan','pelanggan.pelanggan_id = konfirmasi.pelanggan_id','left');
        $this->db->join('pemesanan','pemesanan.id_pemesanan = konfirmasi.pemesanan_id','left');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

please help me, I have looked for ways related to this problem but have not found a solution ...

before that I say thank you to anyone who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this. Codeigniter model returns associative array and you were trying to get the property as std class object.

```
<?= base_url() . 'lihat/transaksi/' . $transaksi['id_pemesanan'] ?>" target="_blank">#<?= $transaksi['id_pemesanan'] ?>
```

Comment: thank you .. your answer is very helpful. but I experienced a new problem shortly after I entered the data and processed it ...
The error message is like this undefined variable Transaksi. can you once again help me because I'm a beginner in CI

Answer (score 0):

You should use isset to check $transaksi has data or not use the following code in view  :

```
<?php

$pemesananid = isset($transaksi->id_pemesanan) ? $transaksi->id_pemesanan : 0;

echo base_url() . 'lihat/transaksi/' . $pemesananid; ?>" target="_blank">#<?= $transaksi->id_pemesanan

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've presented wrong `model`. You're using `TransaksiModel`, not `KonfirmasiModel`.

```
$data['transaksi'] = $this->TransaksiModel->myTransaction();
```

Based on returning result from `myTransaction()` you should understand how you can use it later.

If it returns an array:

```
$transaksi['key']
```

If it returns an object:

```
$transaksi->key
```

If it can be sometimes empty - you must check it with help of `isset()` or `empty()` or both at once.

*Each undefined property (in case of an object) / index (in case of an array) will raise you an error.*

If you're using a PHP variable, which wasn't declared before - you will get a common undefined error.

*A small tip:* use `base_url('lihat/transaksi/' . $variable)`

Answer (score 0):

**use this and also print it and check you data getting an object or array**

```
$transaksi['id_pemesanan']// used if data getting array
```